# How to plot long legends with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot long legends of a multiple lines chart at the bottom of the chart. How can I do that without using a smaller font for legends?
The following example uses 6 lines but I also use graphs with more lines.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(d = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6),
             name = c("long long long long long text 1",
                      "long long long long long text 1",
                      "long long long long long text 2",
                      "long long long long long text 2",
                      "long long long long long text 3",
                      "long long long long long text 3",
                      "long long long long long text 4",
                      "long long long long long text 4",
                      "long long long long long text 5",
                      "long long long long long text 5",
                      "long long long long long text 6",
                      "long long long long long text 6"),
             year = c(2010, 2011, 2010, 2011, 2010, 2011, 2010, 2011,
                      2010, 2011, 2010, 2011),
             value = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.6,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = year, y = value)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = name, linetype = name), size = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = name, color = name), size = 2) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=rel(1.5), angle=90),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=rel(1.5)),
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.text=element_text(size=rel(1.5)),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.line = element_line(color = 'black'),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank()) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(2010, 2011, by = 1)) +
  labs(
    title = "Chart title",
    x = NULL,
    y = "No."
  ) +
  ylim(0, 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control the number of rows or column using a `guide` function:

```
p + scale_color_discrete(guide = guide_legend(ncol = 1))
```

Where `p` is your plotting code above.

[image]